# QDialog with transparent background shows up as black

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, transparency, qdialog

I have `QDialog`, which is modal and takes the whole screen, meaning it spans itself across all the monitors and I want to make it transparent. Initially I `went setWindowOpacity()` and it worked, but after that everything else I would draw on the dialog using `QPainter` it would draw opaquely, which was understandable. Because this wasn't the solution I was looking for I ended up doing `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground)` and to my surprise the background ended up being black. The same thing happens when I do `setStyleSheet("QDialog {background-color: transparent;}")`. Has anyone else seen this issue and how do I fix it?

Some code snippets:

```
SnipAreaDialog::SnipAreaDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  setCursor(Qt::CrossCursor);
}

void SnipAreaDialog::showEvent(QShowEvent *event) {
  auto desktopRect = qApp->desktop()->geometry();
  setGeometry(desktopRect);
  QDialog::showEvent(event);
}
```

Also, I am showing the dialog with `QDialog::exec()` and I tried setting its parent to 0, as well as to the main window of my app, it's the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also had a situation, try like this, it helped me...
example below

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog() : QDialog(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint) 
    {
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog d;
    d.showFullScreen();
    return a.exec();
}
```

> if there isn't a parent, you may consider using
>   `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` as well. If the window system supports it, a
>   tool window can be decorated with a somewhat lighter frame. It can
>   also be combined with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` .